# Displaying List of Map in form:select

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC framework. I am trying to figure out how to display a list inside a map in the jsp.

assuming "age" is populated, how do I loop through the object to get the value?

our DB have a field, key, value. Example: age, N, 21.

```
List<Map<String, String>> age;
model.addAttribute("age", age);
```

```
<form:select path="indicator" required="true" class="form-control float_left" id="indicator" name="indicator">
    <form:option value="" label="--- Select Age ---"/>
    <form:options items="${age}" itemLabel="123" itemValue="123" />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:forEach var="age" items="${age}">
Key is ${age.key}
Value is ${age.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Since first is the list your getting and the a Map to work with

```
<form:select path="indicator" required="true" class="form-control float_left" id="indicator" name="indicator">
<form:option value="" label="--- Select Age ---"/>
<c:forEach var="age" items="${age}">
<form:options items="${age.key}" itemLabel="123" itemValue="${age.value}" />
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```